# Buy or build tool for Data Reporting?

Tags: reporting

We have been asked to provide a data reporting solution. The followng are the requirements:

i. The client has a lot of data which is generated everyday as an outcome of the tests they run. These tests are run at several sites and they get automatically backed up into a central server.

ii. They already have perl scripts which post process them and generates excel based reports.

iii. They need a web based interface for comparing those reports and they need to mark and track issues which might be present in those data.

I am confused if we should build our own tool for this or we should go for already exiting tool(any suggestions?). Can you please provide supportive arguments for the decision that you would suggest?

Comment: you are asking people to make an architectural and business decision on your behalf. One which they will not have to support or use....

Comment: @Mitch: I am new to data managing and reporting. For sure those who suggest solutions would have had better experience than me - and I am going to take decision only when I am convinced that it is the right way to go. How else would you suggest I proceed?

Comment: Please check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507587/high-quality-alternatives-to-hp-mercury-quality-center) thread - it's essentially the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to narrow down your requirements (what kind of data needs to be compared, and in which format?). Then check if there is already a software available (commercial or free) that fulfills your needs. Based on that, decide if its better (i.e. cheaper) to implement the functionality yourself, or use the other software.

**Don't reinvent the wheel.**

There are quite a few tools out there that specialise in this sort of thing, my gut feeling is that you can find something ready made that does what you need.

As a side note, that tool may also be a better solution for creating those excel reports than the perl scripts.

Comment: Can you suggest some of the tools that exist for these kind of application so that I can evaluate them? What are these kind of tools called in general?

Comment: I only know a tool for statistical process control. But that can be configured to dig into every kind of SPC database structure. If your data is financial, google for "financial reporting tool". Sorry I can not be more specific...